# Slide a div from the bottom underneath another div with angular animations

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-animations

As you can see in the screenshot below, I hava a tab on the bottom of my page. When I click on it, I want it to slide underneath the `<div>` containing "Test" using angular animations. The problem is, that the pagesize should be responsive and therefore I cannot use px-values. I tried percentage as well, but that value refers to my tab-div, not the overall height.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udof8.png)

My component:

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'app-test',
   templateUrl: './test.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
   animations: [
      trigger('tabState', [state('default', style({
            transform: 'translateY(0)'
            })
         ),
         state('open', style({
            transform: 'translateY(-100%)'
         })),
         transition('default <=> open', animate(500))
      ])
   ]})

export class TestComponent {
   state = 'default';
   onComeIn() {
      this.state === 'default' ? this.state = 'open' : this.state = 'default';
   }
}
```

My HTML:

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
   <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
         <span>Test</span>
      </div>
   </mat-toolbar>

   <div class="mainContentContainer">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column" style="height: 100%">
      <div>content</div>
   <div class="mt-auto">
      <div class="tabContainer" [@tabState]="state">
         <div class="tab" (click)="onComeIn()">Tab</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And finally the css:

```css
.tab {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 4.2em;
   width: 33%;
   background-color: white;
   padding: 1em 1.2em 0.45em 1.2em;
   border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0 0;
   box-shadow: 0 0.05em #b7b7b7;
}

.mainContainer {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}

.mainContentContainer {
   flex: 1;
   background-color: #455864;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz out of your code ?

Comment: I tried: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxmwzr

Comment: Is this the behavior your are trying to have ? : https://angular-yj7kej.stackblitz.io

Comment: Not quite, the Tab should initially be on the bottom of the screen (which it is in my project) and then slide up, so that the border of the white tab is right underneath the "Test"-div.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are describing : https://stackoverflow-51765996.stackblitz.io ?

Comment: Yes, this is the behaviour. What did you use to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is more about css :

I changed the initial value of the `tabContainer` class to this :

```
.tabContainer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then in the animation definition, removed the `bottom` and added the `top` one :

```
state('open', style({
  bottom: 'initial',
  top: '20px'
})),
```

[Here is the running example in editor.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-51765996)

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to work exactly how I want it to! :)